# Do all stationary points on a function have the same mathematical properties?

Tags: probability, optimization

I have the following question on properties of a function at their stationary points. To give some context to my question, I will break it up into parts.

**Part 1:**

Suppose we take the Poisson Probability Distribution:

\begin{equation}
P(X=k;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
\end{equation}

We can define the likelihood function as:

\begin{equation}
L(\lambda; x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i=k_i;\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda^{k_i} e^{-\lambda}}{k_i!}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
l(\lambda; x) = \ln L(\lambda; x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [k_i \ln \lambda - \lambda - \ln (k_i!)]
\end{equation}

To find the MLE, we take the derivative (i.e. **stationary point**) of the log-likelihood with respect to $\lambda$, set it to zero, and solve for $\lambda$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dl}{d\lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [ \frac{k_i}{\lambda} - 1] = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i
\end{equation}

**Part 2:** After having derived the MLE of the Poisson Distribution, we can apply the "useful" **properties** of MLE theory to this MLE (e.g. https://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/vdukic/Bayes/likprinc_lect2.pdf). This includes properties such as:

- Consistency : The sample value of the MLE estimator approaches the true value as the sample size approaches infinity
- Asymptotic Normality: The distribution of the MLE estimator approaches a Normal Distribution as the sample size approaches infinity
- Efficiency (via Cramer-Rao Lower Bound) : The variance of the MLE estimator is lowest possible variance out of all similar estimators
- Invariance: If $\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}}$ is the MLE estimator of $\lambda$, then $g(\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}})$ is the MLE estimator of $g(\lambda)$

**Part 3:** In the above example (Part 1), there was a single and analytical (closed-form) solution for $\lambda$.

For more complicated problems, the likelihood function will have multiple dimensions which will result in multiple parameters being estimated e.g. $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}$ = ($\hat{\lambda_1}$, ...., $\hat{\lambda_n}$). This means that this likelihood function will have to be numerically optimized, and the numerical optimization algorithm runs the risk of getting stuck in a local minima/maxima. This also means that a candidate solution vector $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}$ might not be the solution that actually returns the absolutes/true maximum value of the likelihood function : This means that there could be some other $\hat{\theta*}_{\text{MLE}}$ solution vector that is true maximum likelihood estimate. But in reality, we have no way of knowing if our solution from the numerical algorithm is the true solution - and if the MLE theoretical properties (from Part 2) also apply to the solution from the numerical algorithm.

**My Question:** In such instances as described in Part 3, do the theoretical properties from Part 2 only apply to $\hat{\theta*}_{\text{MLE}}$ , or would they apply to $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}$ as well? **Do the theoretical MLE properties apply to ALL stationary points of the likelihood function - or only the global maximum?**

Thanks!

**References:** https://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/vdukic/Bayes/likprinc_lect2.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437637/maximum-likelihood-principle-local-vs-global-maxima

Comment: I'm not aware of any results that directly answer your question. But your question is likely to have a negative answer, because the properties in Part 2 are only proved for the MLE esimator, in other words the global maximum. You can imagine that any local maxima have no reason to be stable, to not shift around, etc. when the sample size increases. So why would they have any of the nice properties you listed?

Comment: In what you wrote, you seem to be saying that taking a derivative gives you a stationary point. (You actually seem to be saying that the derivative **is** a stationary point.) In fact, you must set the derivative to zero, and only then do you have a stationary point. Perhaps you understand this, but you mention stationary point in a way that makes it seem otherwise.