# How do properties of a function change as you move away from its derivatives?

Tags: probability, functions, derivatives

I have the following question on how the properties of a function change as you move away from points where its derivative are 0. To give some context to my question, I will break it into 3 parts.

**Part 1:**

Suppose we take the Poisson Probability Distribution:

\begin{equation}
P(X=k;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
\end{equation}

We can define the likelihood function as:

\begin{equation}
L(\lambda; x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i=k_i;\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda^{k_i} e^{-\lambda}}{k_i!}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
l(\lambda; x) = \ln L(\lambda; x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [k_i \ln \lambda - \lambda - \ln (k_i!)]
\end{equation}

To find the MLE, we take the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $\lambda$, set it to zero, and solve for $\lambda$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dl}{d\lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} [ \frac{k_i}{\lambda} - 1] = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i
\end{equation}

**Part 2:** After having derived the MLE of the Poisson Distribution, we can apply the "useful" **properties** of MLE theory to this MLE (e.g. https://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/vdukic/Bayes/likprinc_lect2.pdf). This includes properties such as:

- Consistency : The sample value of the MLE estimator approaches the true value as the sample size approaches infinity
- Asymptotic Normality: The distribution of the MLE estimator approaches a Normal Distribution as the sample size approaches infinity
- Efficiency (via Cramer-Rao Lower Bound) : The variance of the MLE estimator is lowest possible variance out of all similar estimators
- Invariance: If $\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}}$ is the MLE estimator of $\lambda$, then $g(\hat{\lambda}_{\text{MLE}})$ is the MLE estimator of $g(\lambda)$

**Part 3:** In the above example (**Part 1**), the MLE had a closed-form analytical solution. But in real world problems, the likelihood function can be multi-dimensional and the derivatives need to be numerically approximated. This means that there is always a risk that the numerically approximated solution to the MLE will not be the exact MLE. And the "useful theoretical properties" (**Part 2**) might not fully apply to the numerically approximated solution.

**My Question:** But to what extent do these theoretical properties apply to the numerically approximated MLE solution .... as the numerically approximated solution moves further away from the true MLE solution?

Using the R programming language, I simulated 100 points from a Poisson Distribution with $\lambda$ = 5. I then calculated the log-likelihood function and the MLE estimated for $\lambda$ based on these 100 simulated points. I then plotted the log-likelihood function alongside the true MLE solution (i.e. $\lambda = 5$) , the MLE estimate and two random candidate solutions:

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Simulate 100 points from a Poisson distribution with lambda = 5
data <- rpois(100, 5)

# Estimate lambda using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE)
lambda_mle <- mean(data)

# Define the log-likelihood function
log_likelihood <- function(lambda) {
    sum(dpois(data, lambda, log = TRUE))
}

# Create a sequence of lambda values
lambda_values <- seq(5, 5.5, by = 0.01)

# Calculate the log-likelihood for each lambda value (plotting code has been omitted for brevity, I can post this as well if necessary)
log_likelihood_values <- sapply(lambda_values, log_likelihood)
```

[image]

**In the above graph, since Candidate Solution #1 is closer to the true MLE solution compared to Candidate Solution #2 -  would the theoretical properties of MLE be more applicable to Candidate Solution #1 compared to Candidate Solution #2 ? And how much more applicable?**

In the above graph it might be obvious, but I am not sure how this concept generalizes to higher dimensional problems.

**Is there some mathematical proof which can show that certain theoretical properties known at the true solution .... are more applicable to candidate (numerical) solutions that are closer to the true solution compared to candidate solutions that are further away from the true solution?**

Thanks!

**Note:**

- I am wondering if there some mathematical framework here, e.g. draw a ball of radius "r" around the likelihood function at its true MLE solution. Perhaps, there might be some mathematical proof that shows ALL solutions located exactly "r" units away from the true solution are just as good (so long as they are valid solutions, e.g. certain MLE parameters have constraints, e.g. variance estimates are non-negative)?
- Using the same logic, if $r_1$ > $r_2$, then .... the set of all solutions located exactly $r_2$ units away from the true MLE are "better" than the set of all solutions located exactly $r_1$ units away from the true MLE?

[image]

Comment: The properties you listed are asymptotic properties, so if you can estimate the difference of your approxmation to the MLE and the MLE, then you get asymptotic results for your approximations. For example, if you show that the difference times $\sqrt{n}$ goes to 0 in probability, then you get asymptotic normality for your approximations to the MLE

Comment: @Kakashi nice comment +1

Comment: @Kakashi: thank you for your reply! Can you please explain this a bit more? I understand the importance of sqrt(n) : as "n" becomes larger, the ML estimate is expected to become closer to the real ML value. But can it be shown that for a fixed value of "n", an estimate closer to the real ML value is better than an estimate located further away? I expect that is an obvious fact ... but I was just curious in knowing if there is a mathematical proof for this? Thank you so much

Comment: @stats_noob It would depend on what you mean by one estimator being better than another. In some cases, for certain definitions of better, there are estimators clearly better than the MLE.

Comment: @Kakashi:  thank you for your reply! here is the original problem that motivated my question. When creating statistical models, we often have to optimize very complicated likelihood functions using numerical algorithms (e.g. fisher scoring, i.e. newton-raphson).

Comment: I was worried that it is inevitable that numerical algorithms might get stuck and not return the true likelihood estimate. So, given some data, if the true ML estimate value is 5, your numerical estimate is 5.1 and mine is 11.6 (e.g. highly non-convex likelihood function, mine got stuck in a saddle point or local minima) ... clearly, your answer is closer to the real answer compared to mine. but in real world applications, we have no way of knowing this ... and I would falsely conclude that my ML estimate has theoretical properties that are not entirely true

Comment: this is actually a related question I had on this same topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803702/do-all-stationary-points-on-a-function-have-the-same-mathematical-properties

Comment: @stats_noob For investigating these detailed questions, you would need to look at the assumptions made in the proofs of the theoretical properties. For example, if your algorithm finds a maximizer of the MLE when you restrict the parameter space, then it is still an MLE. But it general, you find a maximum over a different region of the parameter space each time since the function you maximize, $\theta \mapsto \ell_{\theta}(X)$ is random, so you need to do more detailed analysis.